# plotly in R : feeding add_trace with data from a list() object

Tags: r, plotly

I have data that is already stored in a list object. I have several lines to draw one one top of the other. I would like to plot them using plotly WITHOUT converting the data into a data frame. In the code below, the first line draws fine, but the additional lines do not draw with add_trace() :

```
library(plotly)
d1 = list(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4))
d2 = list(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4)+2)
p<-plot_ly(d1,x=x,y=y)
p<-add_trace(d2,x=x,y=y)
p
```

giving the error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

any ideas?
thanks

PS : by the way I also find it quite strange that plot_ly does not work without x=x, y=y. I know data is stored like that internally in plotly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
d1 = list(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4))
d2 = list(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,3,4)+2)
p<-plot_ly(d1,x=x,y=y) %>% add_trace(x=d2[[1]], y=d2[[2]])
p
```

Comment: So easy, so obvious. Thanks. I still think that the syntax has to be standardized, though.

Comment: I know! Don't forget to accept the answer if it fixes your problem :-)